# Facebook app token and user token shows different feeds for the same page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am parsing posts from specified Facebook Page using both app level and user tokens.

And for some reason output is different. User level token gives me 3 posts :

post 1 
post 2
post 3

But application token shows only post 3.

Why application token can't get all post from page ?

Facebook page ID is "fifa". Tested both graph api and fql in Graph API Explorer.

Comment: The posts may be gated in some way. Only available in one country for example